# In AngularJS, can I append a ng-repeat $index to the property name of a ng-model directive?

Tags: angularjs

Is there anyway to append the ng-repeat $index to the value of a ng-model directive?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in GiantList">
    <input type="text" value="" ng-model="saveData.MyProperty+[$index+1]">
</div>
```

Ideally, this would mean that:

> $scope.saveData = [{ "MyProperty1" : "Bob" }, { "MyProperty2" : "Sam" }, { "MyProperty3" : "Chris" }]

I've tried every syntactical combination I can think of to no avail.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is clear. You want to get the friend#($index) of the saveData[$index]?

Comment: `ng-model="saveData[item.Name+$index]` seems to work (but not `[item.Name+$index+1]`)

Comment: item.Name + ($index + 1)

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thanks that worked! I updated the code above to more closely reflect my actual production code. It's actually a little simpler, but is still causing me an issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" value="" ng-model="saveData['MyProperty'+($index+1)]">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/oIaKmp4I0IlBb4BNLHPZ?p=preview)

Comment: That's it! Many thanks- you solved the riddle. So many choices with {{ }}, [ ] , and ' '- I can never figure out which ones to use. Thank you!!!!

Comment: It's weird that this answer works because your saveData is an array and you use it like an object (you look directly for a property without selecting an object in the array first... are you sure the saveData in your question is similar to the one in your application?

Comment: @Galdo You are right- this demo I typed up is not correct. I was basically trying to figure out the syntactical magic to be able to manipulate the value of the ng-model field using string concatenations.

Comment: Well! If someone read this and is in the situation shown in the question, check my answer :) But note that if you need to use my answer, it's because your app have a design issue :P the properties of the items in the array should be the same for each object. If your project is well made, this answer is the right one :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question but try this :

http://plnkr.co/edit/3qClmN

```
saved[$index]['friend'+($index+1)]
```

Comment: Good luck with your project!